# git pom.xml postinstallScriptlet

Tags: git, maven, pom.xml

Can I put multiple scriptFile entries in the pre/post install/remove scriptlet section of a pom.xml file? When creating a pom.xml file, it appears that the pom.xml file does not allow two scriptFile entries in the pre/post install/remove scriptlet sections. Testing leads me to believe that only the last scriptfile in the scriptlet section gets executed. I did a search of the internet and failed to find the pom.xml requirements that either limit the number of scriptFile entries or described how to structure multiple entries within a scriptlet section. Is this a restriction of one scriptfile per scriptlet section or is there a way to have 2 or more scriptfile entries for a given scriptlet section?

Comment: I guess you're talking about the configuration of a specific plugin, since there are no scriptFile entries in the pom.xml ( see http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.1/maven-model/maven.html )

Comment: Here's the specific tags:  <preinstallScriptlet>    <script>echo "Scheduler installation started."</script>
    </preinstallScriptlet>
    <postinstallScriptlet> <scriptFile>scripts/scheduler_install</scriptFile>
 <scriptFile>scripts/resolver_install</scriptFile>     </postinstallScriptlet>

Comment: You must be talking about http://mojo.codehaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/rpm-mojo.html right?